# What does $^t$ mean in $x={}^t(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$

Tags: notation, finite-fields

I'm reading [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-38616-9_8) paper and came across some notation I don't know and which is pretty difficult to search for. The relevant section is the first paragraph of section 2.1 in the paper, copied below:

Let $q$ be a power of prime and $k$ be a finite field of order $q$. For integers $n, m\ge1$, denoted by $f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_m(x)$ quadratic polynomials of $x={}^t(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ over $k$.

**Question:** What is the meaning & name of the $^t$ notation before the brackets? It is not defined and is obviously not an exponent due to its placement. They use it in a similar fashion later in section 2.2:

$$
f_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)={}^txF_ix+ \text{(linear.)}
$$

where $F_1,...,F_m$ are $n×n$ matrices over $k$

Comment: It means transpose I guess

Comment: I think the preceding superscript $t$ is the Bourbaki notation for the transpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the transpose. It is an aesthetic notation.

Instead of writing a vector as column, you would write it as a row.

So $(1,2,3)^t=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: And they use it in the beginning of the vector to avoid the ambiguity of it being an exponent?

Comment: The exponent of a vector is not defined, as you can not multiply a vector with itself anyways (for that we would need a scalar product), so there should no confusion accour. It is just the choice of notation. I think it is more common to write the $^t$ at the end, instead of the beginning, as I did it above.

Comment: The $t$ should be in upright shape, and precede the matrix.

Comment: @Cornman thanks. I've seen it as $x^\intercal$ in other places. I guess different notation for different authors

Comment: @flipchart I think as many notations it varies from country to country. In France I was taught with $^tA$ and saw $A^T$ only later reading stuff in English, don't know if it is English related or American related though. Now with internet, notations spread and you get a mix of everything...

Comment: I think in germany it is also more common to write $A^t$. In the book 'Advanced Linear Algebra' by Steven Roman, he also writes $A^t$. So there are many different notations for that $^TA$, $A^T$, $^tA$, $A^t$, the french notation ....